# Permissions for Azure app using Microsoft Graph to read SharePoint Online

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

This seems like a simple question but I'm struggling to find an answer anywhere. Help! ;-)

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph to read SharePoint lists/libraries in a SharePoint site, however this is just for one site (for our department) amongst many on our SharePoint online. I've registered an Azure AD app (with secret etc...) and requested 'application' permissions for the Microsoft Graph ('Create, edit, and delete items and lists in all site collections') and its saying 'admin consent required' is 'yes' and its currently flagged as 'not granted for *****'.

My boss is now asking - with a worried tone ;-)

> will this mean the app can basically read/write/delete on all sites in
>   the organisations SharePoint (not just our site) if our IT department
>   'consent'?

I said I don't know actually... I guess I'm not entirely clear on which permissions this is for, is it just to call the Microsoft Graph API or is it for this app to access SharePoint itself? I've searched for answers to this but I'm struggling to find anywhere that says anything about giving your app permissions in SharePoint, it all seems to be about getting permissions for the Microsoft Graph to access SharePoint.

I just want the app to have permissions to read/write lists/files in this one SharePoint site, not any others (we have loads of sites for other departments). I feel like we should be adding permissions for this app (its service principal?) somewhere on the SharePoint site we want to access, but what permissions do I need to setup and where so this app can only access this one site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is still missing. It is not possible to limit the permissions to only one SharePoint site. It's either access to all SharePoint sites in the organisation or none. Check out the user vote for more information: [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37796059-restrict-permissions-to-app-only-azure-ad-applicat). Microsoft is still working on providing a way to limit the access to specific resources.

Comment: Thanks for that, pity it can't be isolated to individual sites/lists/etc...hopefully Microsoft will respond to that uservoice request ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD app registration now allows for granular access to SharePoint site collection, there is a new option Sites.Selected under Azure AD App Registration - Request API Permissions  - refer to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/

Comment: Nice one, thanks for letting me know about that, finally they've added it... looks like just what I need :-)